# I don't need Hubspot HUBL variables {{ standard_header_includes }}, how can I skip this requirement for AMP Page?

Tags: amp-html, hubspot, amp-stories, hubl

I created a template in Hubspot to publish a WebStorie using AMP. I put the code from scratch and Hubspot show me that I must to insert the variables `{{ standard_header_includes }}` and  `{{standard_footer_includes}}` in the head tag and the last one before the body closing tag.

The fact is that I don't need this variables because they are used for style and Hubspot Analytics. I'm going to use the AMP tags for analytics. This variables are causing problems because once render the webstorie, it creates code that is not alloewd by AMP.

I found this instruction in Hubspot page but I can't find this option in HUbspot:

> To publish a coded file as an editable page or blog template, the following variables must be included. If you want to publish an HTML file without these variables, to use within another template, you can do so by unchecking the option "Make this template available for new content".

Somebody has idea of how can I delete this variables for this template without errors?